# How to open windows explorer like Sharepoint does?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sharepoint

In Sharepoint I have a command to see a collection inside windows explorer (really handly if you ask me).

How can I tell Windows explorer to open directly that URL without having to go inside Sharepoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, my research shows that it should be possible if you use `file://` instead of `http://` or `https://`.

```
http://sharepointsite/doclibrary/
```

becomes

```
file://sharepointsite/doclibrary/
```

The SharePoint site has to be in your trusted sites list in IE.

In response to your request for a CLI way of opening the location. I can confirm that if you prefix the location with `explorer` it opens the location. It did take some time to open but that might be the large library I chose.

```
explorer file://sharepointsite/doclibrary/
```

Comment: Do you mean file://sharepointsite/doclibrary/? (I edited the answer myself, correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: And to make the answer an excelllent one, do you know how to do it from a CMD? :)

Comment: Yeah thanks, it was the work night out last night :S

Comment: I expected that but it does not work, it opens My Documents :S

Comment: I've tested in two environments. In the environment where our SP is a trusted site it works, when testing in the environment where it is not trusted I get the behaviour you describe. Can you confirm that your SP site is in the trusted zone?

Comment: Yes, it is on the trusted zone. I even lowered the Security level to Low for the trusted zones and still nothing. Do I have to reboot or to have a specific IE installed?

Comment: We have the latest IE11. I didn't reboot, the only difference between the 2 is that the SharePoint url is missing from the trusted zone.

Comment: Nice, if I execute it from a cmd script it does not work, if I do it from the cmd direclty it works. Of ccourse I need it from a script otherwise makes no sense.

Comment: I know this is very old now but did you get it resolved? Is the script running with elevated privileges?

Comment: I finally added the sharepoint site as a shared folder in the Explorer and it fulfill my needs.